# Display event in calendar from start date to end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, calendar

I have a `Event` Model with attributes `start_time`, `end_time` and `title`. I want to display the events in a calendar format where the events can be seen from their start date until the date it ends. I am using `simple_calendar` gem for displaying the calendar. The github page for the gem is [here](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar). Below is the code that I am using which currently shows the events on their start date. Can I use `simple_calendar` to render the view in the way I want or can someone help me in how do I loop the events in the calendar so that I can write the logic from scratch and display the events from start date to end date?

**Calendar page:**

```
<%= month_calendar events: @events do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <div>
      <%= event.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a hash with keys as date and values as arrays of `Event`'s. The events which spanned multiple days were present in the hash multiple times for every date key which the event was present. Now I just checked if there were any events for the date while rendering and print it if true.

**Controller**

```
def calendar
  @date_events = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  Events.all.each do |event|
    (event.starts_at.to_date..event.ends_at.to_date).each do |dt|
      @date_events[dt].push(event)
    end
  end
end
```

**calendar.html.erb**

```
<%= month_calendar do |date| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% if @date_events[date] %>
    <% @date_events[date].each do |event| %>
      <div>
        <%= event.title %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```